# What does 'MutVar#' mean?

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-optimization, ghci

I've been trying to read and understand the code that implements Haskell's ST monad,
and I found [this code](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/df3b1d43cc862fe03f0724a9c0ac9e7cecdf4605/libraries/base/GHC/STRef.hs):

```
{-# LANGUAGE Unsafe #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude, MagicHash, UnboxedTuples #-}
{-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK hide #-}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- |
-- Module      :  GHC.STRef
-- Copyright   :  (c) The University of Glasgow, 1994-2002
-- License     :  see libraries/base/LICENSE
--
-- Maintainer  :  cvs-ghc@haskell.org
-- Stability   :  internal
-- Portability :  non-portable (GHC Extensions)
--
-- References in the 'ST' monad.
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

module GHC.STRef (
        STRef(..),
        newSTRef, readSTRef, writeSTRef
    ) where

import GHC.ST
import GHC.Base

data STRef s a = STRef (MutVar# s a)
-- ^ a value of type @STRef s a@ is a mutable variable in state thread @s@,
-- containing a value of type @a@

-- |Build a new 'STRef' in the current state thread
newSTRef :: a -> ST s (STRef s a)
newSTRef init = ST $ \s1# ->
    case newMutVar# init s1#            of { (# s2#, var# #) ->
    (# s2#, STRef var# #) }

-- |Read the value of an 'STRef'
readSTRef :: STRef s a -> ST s a
readSTRef (STRef var#) = ST $ \s1# -> readMutVar# var# s1#

-- |Write a new value into an 'STRef'
writeSTRef :: STRef s a -> a -> ST s ()
writeSTRef (STRef var#) val = ST $ \s1# ->
    case writeMutVar# var# val s1#      of { s2# ->
    (# s2#, () #) }

-- Just pointer equality on mutable references:
instance Eq (STRef s a) where
    STRef v1# == STRef v2# = isTrue# (sameMutVar# v1# v2#)
```

I see the following line of code in the above code file :

```
data STRef s a = STRef (MutVar# s a)
```

A quick search on `MutVar#` yielded the following results :

- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.4.1/docs/src/Data-Primitive-MutVar.html#MutVar
- https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/228ddb95ee137e7cef02dcfe2521233892dd61e0/utils/genprimopcode/Main.hs#L816

My question is :
   What is `MutVar#`? Why isn't it defined anywhere ? What does it mean ?

Comment: It seems to be a primitive type [defined in GHC](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/90dd11bf1918485f0f19bb2fb764f1675c0f0dd5/compiler/prelude/primops.txt.pp#L1868). It is the same type used for `IORef`s, with the `s` type argument set to `RealWorld#`.

Comment: It *is* defined somewhere: It's in `GHC.Prim`. The definition is just a blank stub though; as others have said, the real implementation is hard-wired into the compiler. This is a low-level GHC-specific implementation detail. A different Haskell compiler would probably implement it differently.

Answer (score 7):

`MutVar#` is a primitive type provided by the compiler itself. It represents a mutable reference, and forms the core of `IORef` and `STRef`.

In general, anything that ends in `#` is an implementation detail of GHC. Unless you're doing low-level hackery you don't need to worry about them. Most of these operations have wrappers (like `ST`) which are easier to use.

You can read more about these in the [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html) and the [`ghc-prim`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#g:13) package.

Comment: In fact, any `____#` name is a primitive type, like `Int#` and so on. you need `{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}` to enable it.

Comment: @AJFarmar Careful with that wording. "All `___#` names are primitive" is [just a convention](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#magic-hash); it isn't actually enforced by the compiler. You can define your own functions and types ending in `#`, and GHC won't treat them any differently.

Comment: That's true, but conventions in Haskell are pretty well adhered to! That's worth mentioning nonetheless.